# Complexity of evaluating Lagrange polynomial

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, computational-complexity

Given a set of n + 1 data points $(x_i, f(x_i))$
The langrange polynomial is given by:$$\sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i) \frac{(x-x_1)\cdot... (x-x_{i-1})(x-x_{i+1}) \cdot....\cdot(x-x_n)}{w_i}$$ with $w_i:= (x_i-x_1)\cdot ...\cdot(x_i-x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i+1})\cdot....\cdot(x_i-x_n)$

To compute that you consider $$(x-x_1)\cdot...\cdot(x-x_n) \sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i) \frac{1}{w_i(x-x_i)}$$

Why does this computation leads to time complexity $O(n)$?

Comment: Do compute the operation count. (And double check your formula, there is a typo.)

Comment: Why do mean by that.

Comment: I can only be true when $w_k $ are precomputed

Comment: Fix the typo first.

Comment: I fix it. If I know $w_k$ and the factor before the sum, then I only have to add n times. Is it that simple?

Comment: Yep, it takes $O(n^2)$ products to compute the $w_k$, then you can use the division trick to evaluate the interpolator in linear time. Note that the $O(n^2)$ term is recovered when the interpolate at more than $O(n)$ points.

Comment: $O(n^2)$ is because of the fact, that I compute n times $w_i $ which has n factors?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: So I can evalute the polynomial for any x in linear time?

Comment: In the first formula I can also pre -compute the weights and evalute in linear time. Where is the difference?

Comment: The first formula takes $O(n^2)$ for any new $x$.

Comment: I do not see the difference. The second is for new x also in $O(n^2)$

Comment: How so ? Please detail.

Comment: I can compute the numerator and $w_k$ in the first formula. I only have to add n terms when I want to compute for special x